# How to make ImageIcon move around JPanel?

Tags: java, keyboard

I cannot figure out why the KeyEvent will not change to the gif and move my sprite

tried changing the way I load my image but for some reason the KeyEvent does not display any change within the JPanel.

tried changing the way I load my JPanel but for some reason the KeyEvent does not display any change within the JPanel.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.OverlayLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Level1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final Color COLOR1 = Color.BLACK;
    private static final Color COLOR2 = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;

    private JPanel gamePanel;
    private JButton quit;
    private JLabel introLabel;

    protected JFrame lvl1;

    ImageIcon lvl, sprite;

    private int x = 500, y=500;

    public Level1() {

        lvl1 = new JFrame("ROAMING");
        lvl1.setSize(640, 480);

        lvl = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\srs42\\Sprites\\LEVEL1.gif");
        JLabel icon = new JLabel(lvl);

        sprite = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\srs42\\Sprites\\Sprite.gif");
        JLabel spriteLabel = new JLabel(sprite);

        gamePanel = new JPanel();

        spriteLabel.setLocation(x, y);
        icon.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        icon.add(spriteLabel);

        introLabel = new JLabel("//: ROAMING");
        introLabel.setForeground(COLOR1);
        gamePanel.add(introLabel);

        quit = new JButton("Quit");
        quit.addActionListener(this);
        quit.setBackground(COLOR2);
        quit.setOpaque(true);
        gamePanel.add(quit);

        gamePanel.add(icon);

        lvl1.add(gamePanel);
        lvl1.setVisible(true); 
        //player.play("\\Users\\srs42\\Songs\\Mixdown\\Song2.wav");
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        sprite = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\srs42\\Sprites\\walking_down.gif");
        }
    }
```

displays level and sprite but sprite does not change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing ImageIcon to another picture with button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994421/changing-imageicon-to-another-picture-with-button-click)

Comment: I don't see where you are updating your x and y coordinates.

Comment: No idea what is this about, but it looks like you just assign new instance of an image to your private field `sprite`. But `spriteLabel` still has old image, and it is not aware of your actions in the key event handler. Try to actually update it by doing `spriteLabel.setIcon(sprite)` after you have assigned new value to `sprite`.